# A idiomatic term that describes a mentality that is supportive and empowering

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

The term [Crab Mentality](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=crab%20mentality) has been defined as:

> *Analogous to the behaviour of a person who diminishes or pulls down 
>   anyone else who achieves or is about to achieve success greater than 
>   their own.*

I was looking for a idiomatic term that describes a mentality that is the opposite of Crab mentality. IOW, a term that best describes  a ***Supportive*** and ***Empowering*** mentality of a person?

*Context*: The newly elected Head of State is providing constant support and encouragement to those people in his country who intends to become entrepreneurs.

*Example sentence*: The newly elected Head of State, who is famous for his *supportive & empowering* mentality, has already set the tone for a new way of doing business in Country XX.

So, in the above sentence I would like to replace the two words "supportive and empowering" with a more idiomatic term.

Comment: I can think of several ways of conveying this idea, but they would be used in different ways.  Could you give us a sample sentence?

Comment: @aparente001 For example if a person constantly strives his best to encourage people to achieve something, how would you describe the mentality of that person? Does this example help? Thanks.

Comment: @D_S That's a *coach* and he's *supportive* and *empowering*.

Comment: @DanBron: Thanks. So what term will you use to describe such a mentality? A mentality that is supportive and empowering?

Comment: @D_S The words in italics in my earlier comment were th only ones I could think of to offer.

Comment: A crab is crabby; a dog is supportive. Never heard of *crab mentality*, but OK, then perhaps *dog mentality*?

Comment: Please see if my edit to your question helps you frame your question in a way that will optimize your results.

Comment: @aparente001 Yes your edit does help in describing the context. Is there still a need for an example sentence? Thanks.

Comment: @MartinSmith That's because the context describes the scenario

Comment: D_S: I took a wild stab at writing a fill-in-the-blank sentence for you.  It's probably *not* what you have in mind -- so could you please edit your question and adjust the fill-in-the-blank sentence, to fit what *you're* looking for?

Comment: @aparente001 Thank You. I have edited a part of the sentence that you wrote. I hope this will make it clear.

Comment: D_S: Progress!  Now you need to explain why the phrase you rejected, "supportive and empowering mentality", doesn't do the trick for you.  For example -- maybe "I need something more idiomatic / modern / old-fashioned" or "I need a buzz word" or "I need something less hackneyed" or "I need something more unusual, designed to impress people with my large vocabulary" -- whatever it is, just be honest.

Comment: @aparente001 So, I have edited the question to suggest that I'm looking for a idiomatic term that has the same meaning as supportive and empowering.

Comment: Very good.  Sorry if the process was difficult.  I think your question is going to take off now!  I will add "can-do" to my answer and others may have additional ideas.

Comment: Motivating ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idiom that doesn't mean exactly the same thing, literally, but which expresses the feeling I think you're aiming for.

[***can-do***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/can-do)

`willing to try different ways to solve problems and confident that you will succeed (always before noun): *Her can-do attitude is the reason we chose her for the job.*`

*(Cambridge Idioms Dictionary)*

> I am fed up with the crab mentality that was so prevalent under the previous administration.  Mr. X's ***can-do attitude*** has already set the tone for a new way of doing business in Country Y.

Answer (score 1):

**altruistic support** refers to unselfish concern and active support.

- "I would like to thank my brother for his **altruistic support**, encouragement, and belief in me and in everything I do."
- "This study was conducted with the **altruistic support** of two great teachers who I wish to thank..."
- "Consumers do not buy simply out of **altruistic support** for those who need to increase their sales revenue."

Comment: @Cascabel   You're right. It simply slipped my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Although the person who had asked the question has already chosen an answer, however, even that person and other visitors to the site may find the following information useful:

**Transformative mentality**

The Cambridge Online Dictionary for advanced learners of the language defines the term **[transformative](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/transformative)** as follows:

> causing a major change to something or someone, especially in a way that makes it or them better

Considering that a simple search for the phrase on Google generates over 300,000 results, I believe that it has some traction amongst the authors.